# PostgreSQL dynamic conditions in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have one table: **categories**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     category_id     |        name      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     'text 1'     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     'text 2'     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

We need to do this:

**Pseudo SQL code**:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE case when $1 != 0 then category_id = $1 end;
```

`$1` - input parameter's value

Is It possible to do it in PostgreSQL with one SQL query?

Comment: It is possible, but usually this leads to inefficient (=slow) execution plans.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thx, but what you can recommend in this case? To make different SQL queries from a programming language with different where conditions?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In most cases this will be way more efficient

Comment: Note that since (presumably) `category_id` won't be `0` the `$1 != 0` part of the test is redundant and you can just write `WHERE category_id = $1` since if `$1` is 0, your original `WHERE` clause will return no rows either

Comment: `WHERE $1 =0 OR $1 = category_id`

Comment: Or `WHERE $1 !=0 AND $1 = category_id` in which case the comment above (by Nick) applies.

Comment: That won't work as written, since the `CASE` clause will return a `null` value when $1 = 0, and that's not a boolean value.

Comment: @TheImpaler  In PostgreSQL, NULL is a fine boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c
WHERE $1 = 0 OR c.category_id = $1;
```

This returns all rows if the input parameter is `0` and just the matching row otherwise.

Comment: GordonLinoff, thx for the answer. @a_horse_with_no_name adviced me to avoid using such SQL queries because of performance issues. Programmatically generating SQLs are more preferable in case of highload apps.